# Google reCaptcha keeps loading forever

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm using Google's reCaptcha 2.0 on my website. It used to work well, but since I opened my website to the public and got some more users, recaptcha is not working anymore with most users.. it loads fine, but once the user clicks the "I'm not a robot" checkbox, it keeps loading eternally and never returns a confirmation.

I tried to look all over the web for it, but couldn't find someone with a similar issue, and I have no idea how to (or if I can) debug it, since apparently it's not returning a response from google. All my keys are correct.

Can someone help me out? My website is [www.heropanel.com](http://www.heropanel.com) - to simulate it, click on contact at the bottom of the page, and click the "I'm not a robot" checkbox.

Comment: SO is primarily about troubleshooting your code.  If it was working fine until you got more users, then it sounds like you have a question for Google.

Comment: the same happens to me when i have special charachters in the domain name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723870/make-google-recaptcha-work-with-special-charachters-in-the-domain-name

Comment: When entering heropanel.com to the browser it redirects to https:// heropanel.com. Have you tried if it works without the secure sertificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I found the answer. The captcha was loading inside a modal popup div. When this popup loaded, it would change the div's parent and that somehow broke the captcha (probably some embedded security code). My solution was to reload the captcha after the window popup.

Answer (score 4):

your problem is:

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="light"></div>`

you are missing attribute. the correct will be:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_google_public_key"></div>
```

You hav create **data-sitekey** before use google captcha.

read more at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display and https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#createsite

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. When i click on reCaptcha its just loading and not give the response. Mostly solutions that i found were to reload reCaptcha, but it could not solve my problem.Finally I found that I use bool type variable 'length=false' that cause to create that problem. I jsut change the variable name and solve my problem.

1. Reload or reset reCaptcha by using 'grecaptcha.reset();'.
2. Make sure not use any reserve word(as i mention above) in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue after I switched to SSL
Although everything worked fine on desktop even under http .
Mobile Android reCaptcha continued to spinning without approval