# Make google Recaptcha work with special characters in the domain name

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, recaptcha

I was setting up an API key for a site with the swedish charachter ä in the domain name ([http://sälja.io](http://s%C3%A4lja.io)) but it did not initialize the recaptcha.

Then trying an api key for the equivalent url http://xn--slja-loa.io which worked when reaching the site from http://xn--slja-loa.io but not [http://sälja.io](http://s%C3%A4lja.io).

Then I found the secure token which should work on all domains. It initialized the recaptchas on **all domains** and was also working on **all tested domains, except the one with ä in it**.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token

Is there any way to get it working also with ä in the domain name ?

**Edit**

Since an api-key for http://xn--slja-loa.io is working from android when accessing the site from [http://sälja.io](http://s%C3%A4lja.io), it might be how the browser interprets the domain. Eg. firefox interprets [http://sälja.io](http://s%C3%A4lja.io) as domain [http://sälja.io](http://s%C3%A4lja.io) and cannot get a response from google servers that will not allow ä in domain names. Android inteprets [http://sälja.io](http://s%C3%A4lja.io) as http://xn--slja-loa.io and will get a response since it's not containing ä. Any thoughts about this ? Is there any way to force the browser to interpret [http://sälja.io](http://s%C3%A4lja.io) as http://xn--slja-loa.io ?

**Edit2**

Code examples can be reached on sälja.io/test, 178.62.187.163/test and xn--slja-loa.io/test

**Edit3**

As of today (25.11.2015) it seems not to be possible to use recaptcha with a special charachter like ä in the domain name. Since aishwat singh have been helping the most to coming to this conclusion within the time for the bounty he will be rewarded, however an answer will be accepted when a solution can be provided for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I tried it just now and I am able to generate key for `example-ä.se` *6Ld8VRETAAAAALRXFNxmjEeVzbg2y5vdWv7THwJz*

*will post a complete working example shortly*

---

**EDIT 1**

Here's git [repo](https://github.com/aishwat/re-captcha) for code and same running on [heroku](https://example-%C3%A4.herokuapp.com)

Ok it's not a complete fix because i used herokuapp.com as domain so example-ä.herokuapp.com becomes a sub domain and works

(however when earlier i tried it created a key for `example-ä.se` too but on loading page at captcha it gives `invalid domain`, figured out that was original issue, i thought you were not able to generate key for this domain)

*Will try for a complete fix*

---

**EDIT 2**

Btw you can specify your domain ip too, check this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/recaptcha/domain$20/recaptcha/Ondzsj99YYQ/DVnGC33LkmkJ)

For me heroku free account doesn't provides ip of domain so it's difficult for me to test it

Also i was reading this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/recaptcha/domain$20/recaptcha/hmld0_r6lQs/BCh7aFQkbmAJ)

Figured out if i specify domains list as just `com` it accepts. In your case, just specify `se` as domains and it should work , google doesn't checks out exact url it just checks domain

[image: domain description]

*Hope it helps, Will look into `stoken` approach too*

Comment: I will test your examples later since I'm not infront of my computer right now. You are right, its not about subdomains but a domain. Btw, I think the problem is in the browser since it is working from my android phone, but not browsers such as firefox or explorer.

Comment: @embe ok vl give it a try on firefox and ie

Comment: I've tried now and cannot get it working. Only trying firefox and android since i'm using ubuntu. The "ip-way" is working only if typing the ip in the browser, not with the "ä-domain". The "domain extension-way" is inititializing the captcha, just like a secure token do, but is not giving a response (not validating), just like the secure token case. The "domain extension-way" is also working from android.

Comment: Think it must be the domain the browser think it has; in firefox case it thinks it is example-ä domain and it's not working with recaptcha servers, in android case it thinks it has example--7za domain and its getting a response. What do you think about this? Is there a way to force the browser to think it has the domain example--7za instead of example-ä ?

Comment: If no one can provide a working solution for firefox I will award the bounty to you as a proof that it's not possible. :-)

Comment: @embe vl give it a try in ff too (which version u r using ?)

Comment: ok just tried `https://example-ä.herokuapp.com/` on firefox 42.0 (os x) and it works, only difference is ff keeps url as `https://example-ä.herokuapp.com/?` whereas chrome renames it to `https://xn--example--7za.herokuapp.com/`
however vl see if both are sending different `host` header

Comment: host is also `xn--example--7za.herokuapp.com` so it all looks ok , can u provide ff version and os u r using and which link u r trying to get or some piece of code

Comment: You are using the domain herokuapp.com, need this to work on a domain, not subdomain. I'm using ubuntu and firefox 42.0. Code examples can be reached on http://sälja.io/test, http://178.62.187.163/test/ and http://xn--slja-loa.io/test/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95864/discussion-between-aishwat-singh-and-embe).

Answer (score -1):

you can read this post:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024

.....................

Comment: I have no problems to implement it. The problem is to get it working with a domain containing ä