# recaptcha V2 error spinning on Samsung browser

Tags: javascript, android, recaptcha

Google Recaptcha V2 has stopped functioning for users on Samsung stock mobile browser on 3 different sister sites at some point in the last few weeks.
After ticking "I am not a robot" the recaptcha is stuck spinning continuously.
Works fine on desktop, mobile chrome and firefox etc. seems limited to Samsung's stock browser on mobile.

My knowledge of Javascript is limited, and I didn't build the site, and from looking at the backend it looks a bit of a mess.

Any help would be appreciated!

Example page
http://www.bubblesoccerworld.com/enquiry-greenockeast-adults.php

[Sample Page stuck loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lxBJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue. And found that recaptcha v2 has issues in some browsers if it is inside modal screen https://stackoverflow.com/a/33920555/2035054

If you are using bootstrap modal you can try to `grecaptcha.reset();` in 'shown.bs.modal' event

But unfortunately it did not work for me