# Google ReCaptcha keeps on loading

Tags: php, joomla, recaptcha

I'm using Google's reCaptcha 2.0 on my website. It used to work well,but then someone emailed me that the captcha keeps on loading 2mins .. 5mins.. 8mins.. and I know this is a problem. Once clicked the "Im not a robot" it loads forever.  I tried to look all over the web for it, but couldn't find someone with a similar issue, and I have no idea how to (or if I can) debug it, since apparently it's not returning a response from google. All my keys are correct I even update it in plugins.

Tried to troubleshoot the code but nothing happened. Already tried the solutions here: [Google reCaptcha keeps loading forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571032/google-recaptcha-keeps-loading-forever) but its not working for me.

Somebody pls help me, thanks.

Comment: You didn't give us a way to reproduce your problem. That might make it hard to find a solution. Notice how the question you're referencing did do that.

Comment: I've already tried to update Key and versions but it doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happened to me yesterday on my Joomla 3 site. Someone told me it's something called [MooTools](https://mootools.net/) that gets loaded automatically in Joomla 3 interacting badly with other components (I've no idea why that's happening now after all these years) so I installed and enabled the plugin https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mootools-enabler-disabler/ and now reCaptcha works fine again. That plugin disables mootools on all pages by default, apparently you can change the settings to enable or disable it per menu item if necessary but so far I haven't found a need for it to be enabled anywhere. I hear mootools is not loaded by default in Joomla 4.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to install it but it shows an error installing plugin and warning JFolder could not create folder and Extension install failed to create folder. Im jusing Joomla 3.8. any idea about this?

Comment: Already create a folder manually, once I upload the file it says Copy Failed when I manually transfer to folder using SFTP It doesnt reflect on my extensions.

Comment: I'm very much just a basic Joomla user so take any suggestions with a pinch of salt but here we go anyway: I'm on Joomla 3.10.12 - maybe upgrading your Joomla version would help? Also, maybe it's a permissions issue that running [Akeeba Admin Tools Core](https://www.akeeba.com/products/admin-tools.html) "Fix Permissions" tool could help with (of course you may not be able to install that either now, if you don't already have it and then you'd need to check/update permissions manually).

Comment: I expect people could help you more with your original problem if you provided a URL in your question that demonstrates the problem so they could look at that in a debugger to see what's happening. If you can't share a web page for some reason then put `view-source:` in front of the URL that has the problem in your browser (i.e. change `http://whatever` to `view-source:http://whatever`) then look for `mootools` in the source that's displayed then update your question to tell us if that's present or not. Also look at Web Developer Tools "Network" tab in your browser for any clues (idk what).

Answer (score 1):

Hello you just have to download core and more news files 1.6.0 here :

- https://mootools.net/core for download MooTools-Core-1.6.0.js
- https://mootools.net/more for download MooTools-More-1.6.0.js

Back up the existing files at:

- /media/system/js/mootools-core.js
- /media/system/js/mootools-more.js

Rename and upload the new files over the existing files.

Enjoy, it works, because MooTools 1.6.0 is suitable with Joomla 3 and reCAPTCHA!

This is a better solution than removing or disabling MooTools as many Joomla extensions rely on MooTools and expect MooTools to be present.

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for contributing an answer. This is just a note to help you improve your answers. Using links is fine. But, your answer should be useful without the links. When using links, please quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Give credit to the author. Also, explain why your solution works, or how your approach is different from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a thread on forum.joomla.org discussing the same issue.
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=708&p=3706947

Seems that Google doesn't accept the mootools anymore. If your site is loading the mootools it will prevent recaptcha from working.

I installed the plug-in as suggested above. Just enabled it and left everything as default. The recaptcha now works again.

Joomla4 doesn't have this problem because it doesn't have mootools library anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem in two Joomla 3.10 sites.

In the one website I solved it by commenting the line "JHtml::_('script', 'system/mootools..." in line 63 in the behavior.php file.

Unfortunatelly, the second site is using virtuemart and removing mootools breaks the virtuemart admin interface.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My reCaptcha V2 was working fine up until Oct 30, 2023. Then somewhere between then and November 26 it would not work - just kept loading.
Installed the Mootools Enabler/disabler, enabled the plug-in, looked at the options in the plugin which said Mootools disabled. Tried reCaptcha again and lo and behold it worked!

Thank you Thank you to whom ever figured this out. Found this answer on more than one post.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).