# Joomla 2.0 contact form google reCAPTCHA V2 spinning infinitely and not get through verification

Tags: joomla, recaptcha

I added a google reCaptcha v2 on my joomla 2.0 contact form and its not verify and wheel is soining infintely.

I try creating new form and also changed site key and secret key of new reCaptcha. I want it to verify and sumbit form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since late last year, there is a conflict between MooTools and Google reCaptcha on Joomla 3 and presumably earlier versions of Joomla.

There are a few ways to work around this issue:

1. Migrate to Joomla 4.
2. Use hCAPTCHA instead (assuming the extensions you are using support hCAPTCHA).
3. Install an extension to disable Mootools. For example, install jQuery Easy with Extensions -> Plugins -> System - jQuery Easy -> MooTools -> Disable When Possible = "Yes".

Comment: Actually, the best solution is at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77654018/1983389